# Why do almost all DALI master circuits calls for using an interrupt pin for RX?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, lighting, dali

I was searching for the DALI communication part for Dali Master Design and almost all designs use opto isolation circuits (which vary differently in components) and use MCU interrupt pin for DALI receive part (Rx). Can we use any GPIO pins or do we need to use interrupt pins only?

[image]

Got this reference from https://ar.mouser.com/applications/lighting-digitally-addressable/

Comment: you found something, so please link to it! It's kind of unnecessary to guess about design intentions without seeing the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have accurate timing, you must have low latency on the leading edge of the packet.

[The ST datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjZ86WRvsD1AhXlDEQIHaRVATAQFnoECDgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.st.com%2Fresource%2Fen%2Fuser_manual%2Fum1629-stm32l1xx-dali-slave-interface-stmicroelectronics.pdf) itemizes the interface.

[image]

Comment: Which, in no way specifically requires an interrupt pin to do it accurately, there are many other ways of doing it. MCUs have advanced timers that can capture the signal timings in hardware. Some even have configurable peripherals for receiving manchester coded bits. Also, on STM32, any GPIO pin can be configured as an interrupt pin, so it's just easy to use it.

Comment: @Justme  Thanks for clarifying that to other users that the ST document indicates the two GPIO pins are interrupt selectable by software.  But Interrupts or edge detections are necessary no matter how they are created.

Comment: I am confident that interrupts aren't necessary. E.g. you can just sit in a while loop and read the pin, which is definitely not a good way, but possible. On a higher end MCU, a timer could capture pulse transitions in hardware and store their timestamps via DMA and main code could poll if DMA has transferred data. Sure, on a low end MCU, interrupts are just the most convenient way to implement.

Comment: @Justme  I agree Polling  is a waste of time and CPU resources to reduce latency

Comment: Thanks everyone for the informations

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers and comments have noted, an interrupt pin is not necessarily required. Many microcontrollers have timers that will do input capture where the timer measures the pulse width in hardware. You would then interrupt on that event.

Microcontrollers like the ESP32 have the RMT peripheral that measures both the high and low periods and can queue a number of these. You can decide if you want to poll or be interrupted.

There are also more specialist microcontrollers that have DALI peripherals that perform the decode and encoding of the DALI data in hardware.

DALI uses manchester encoding mainly as it allows transformers to be used for isolation (even though optos seem to be more popular) and precise timing is not required as with the usual  uart aerial. This means you don’t require an external crystal for the microcontroller - this has cost benefits.

To decode manchester you either measure the high and low periods and classify them into fat/skinny and high/low then feed that into a state machine or time of an edge and sample the level. An interrupt pin can be used for the edge detection.

I’d suggest having a read of the Wikipedia entry on manchester code for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interrupt pin is just most likely the simplest way which requires least effort from anyone to implement practical reception of DALI data frames, at least when using general purpose microcontrollers for example purposes.

Of course you can use any pin you want if you can write the program to use the pin for reception, but it might not make much sense if using an interrupt pin is easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your micro is implementing a Single Master control device, you *might* be able to use GPIO polling instead of interrupts since the response frame has to occur within a well-defined time window after the forward frame. But you would still need to be able to reliably measure the pulse widths to a few tens of microseconds accuracy so that you can distinguish between valid and invalid pulse widths as per IEC 62386-101. And you would have to be careful that this did not affect other tasks adversely which are naturally blocked during polling.

Similarly, you would have to be more careful than if you used interrupts, that you are not in any other busy loops during the response frame window. Bear in mind that during the response reception, you have to at least shift the recieved bitstream into a buffer for later decoding and decision making.

However, if you are implementing a Multi Master control device or control gear (eg a LED driver) then you've got to be able to measure the pulses at any time so you need as much assistance from the peripherals as you can get eg capture/compare module so that you can run other tasks.